# How do I connect my Debian 9 computer to my Raspberry pi 2 using the ethernet connection to share the pi2 wireless?

Tags: pi-2, debian

I have the recent version of Debian in my computer and a recent version of raspbian in my PI2. I want to connect Debian to Raspberry pi 2 using an ethernet cable, connecting my Debian to share Raspberry pi2 wireless. I am using the Network Manager in Debian 9 and WICD on the Raspberry. Thanks.

Comment: Debian and Raspbian are fully updated and upgraded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bridge the Ethernet and wifi on the pi. Here is a guide https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/. I have not found a working Gui to make this easier. In Ubuntu network manager makes it easy. I installed network masnageron pi but it did not work. Wish I had a easier answer for you.